# C++ interface with CRTP - dynamic_cast to type during runtime

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

I have this code:

```
struct IFoo 
{
   std::string type;
   virtual void foo() = 0;
};

template <typename T>
struct Foo1 : public IFoo 
{
   void foo() override { printf("foo"); }
   void iBar() { static_cast<T *>(this)->bar(); } 
};

struct Bar : public Foo1<Bar> 
{ 
   Bar() { this->type = "Bar"; }
   void bar() { printf("bar"); }
};


void method(IFoo * f1, IFoo * f2)
{
   if ((f1->type == "Bar") && (f2->type == "Bar")){
       method2(dynamic_cast<Bar *>(f1), dynamic_cast<Bar *>(f2));
   }

   //how to call method2 more friendly, then if-else of all possible cases?
};

template <typename T, typename F>
void method2(T * b1, F * b2){
    //here I want to call bar()
};

int main(){
   IFoo * b1 = new Bar();
   IFoo * b2 = new Bar();
   method(b1, b2);
   return 0;
};
```

Is there a way, how to do `dynamic_cast` in `method` more "dynamically"? Currently, If I want to call method2, I have to check all possible combinations of `f1` and `f2` and do `dynamic_cast` and it can be a long list, because I have `Bar`...`BarN` classes. I cannot call method2 directly, because `IFoo` does not have `bar()`.

Comment: *Because IFoo does not have bar()* - That's the gist of your problem right there. The function depends on a property of the object that is not modeled by the type. If you need to call `bar()`, the method should accept as parameter type an interface that has the `bar()` method in it. Unfortunately, your example does not give enough context to propose a more meaningful design.

Comment: @ComicSansMS I know, that is why I have the `dynamic_cast` in `method`. However, if I have N classes, that is a lot of combinations I would have to write. Something like store strng types in `map` and do the look-up and cast based on this?

Comment: Why can't you make an ```IBar``` which has ```bar()``` and make that the parameters of your function? And make different overloaded functions?